# Overlay not to include div

Tags: html, css

I have an `image` inside a well.

When hovering the image/well the the overlay information shows (currently this is correct).

The overlay should cover the whole well (the grey part) in which the image is situated. The `product-title` is below the image/well and is separate from the well.

So when hovering the `product-title` should not be affected (it should actually get a red `background` and the text font `color` should become white).

How to achieve since now the whole thing, including the `product-title` becomes grey upon hovering?

So actually everything is good now, only when hovering the `product-title` div should get its own style and not be "hidden" by the grey overlay.

```css
.product-detailsmas .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #A10000;
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
}

.product-detailsmas {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    text-align: center;
}

.product-detailsmas:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}

.well.sb .product-titlesidebar {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
    color: #444;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="product-detailsmas">
            <div class="image-video-linksidebar">
                <img alt="#" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
                <div class="brandmas">
                    BRAND
                </div>
                <div class="categorymas">
                    CATEGORY
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="intro-descriptioncar">
                    Intro description car
                </div>
                <div class="userfield1car">
                    Userfield-1-car
                </div>
                <div class="userfield1car">
                    Userfield-2-car
                </div>
                <div class="userfield1car">
                    Userfield-3-car
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-titlesidebar">
            CAR TITLE BRAND CATEGORY MODEL-THIS SHOULD NOT BE AFFECTED BY THE OVERLAY HOVER
        </div><!--</div>--></a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ADD**: `position: relative;` to `.product-detailsmas` CSS.

This restricts the absolute positioned element to the parent.

**REMOVE**: the padding on `.product-detailsmas .overlay` -- This is causing the overlay to be larger than the parent.

```css
.product-detailsmas .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    background: #F7F7F7;
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #A10000;
    /* vertical-align: middle; */
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
    transition: opacity 500ms;
}

.product-detailsmas {
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
    text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.product-detailsmas:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
}

.well.sb .product-titlesidebar {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat',sans-serif;
    color: #444;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">
        <div class="product-detailsmas">
            <div class="image-video-linksidebar">
                <img alt="#" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
                <div class="brandmas">
                    BRAND
                </div>
                <div class="categorymas">
                    CATEGORY
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="intro-descriptioncar">
                    Intro description car
                </div>
                <div class="userfield1car">
                    Userfield-1-car
                </div>
                <div class="userfield1car">
                    Userfield-2-car
                </div>
                <div class="userfield1car">
                    Userfield-3-car
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-titlesidebar">
            CAR TITLE BRAND CATEGORY MODEL-THIS SHOULD NOT BE AFFECTED BY THE OVERLAY HOVER
        </div><!--</div>--></a>
    </div>
```

I know it's technically okay, but I personally would *not* load a bunch of separate divs inside an anchor tag.

Comment: thanks, Scott, that worked exactly how I wanted it to work... :)

Answer (score 1):

you need to set `position:relative` in your parent  `.product-detailsmas`, otherwise the `position:absolute` set as it is, would make the element out of the flow with DOM, not the parent element.

and change  `product-titlesidebar` by making it sibling of  `.product-detailsmas`

**Note:** because you are using `width/height:100%` + `padding`, you will need `box-sizing` to avoid scrollbars

```css
.product-detailsmas {
  position: relative
}
.product-detailsmas .overlay {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #A10000;
  /* vertical-align: middle; */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}
.product-detailsmas {
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  text-align: center;
}
.product-detailsmas:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
.well.sb .product-titlesidebar {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: #444;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
    <div class="product-detailsmas">
      <div class="image-video-linksidebar">
        <img alt="#" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100">
        <div class="brandmas">
          BRAND
        </div>
        <div class="categorymas">
          CATEGORY
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="intro-descriptioncar">
          Intro description car
        </div>
        <div class="userfield1car">
          Userfield-1-car
        </div>
        <div class="userfield1car">
          Userfield-2-car
        </div>
        <div class="userfield1car">
          Userfield-3-car
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="product-titlesidebar">
  CAR TITLE BRAND CATEGORY MODEL-THIS SHOULD NOT BE AFFECTED BY THE OVERLAY HOVER
</div>
```